# Fill in missing rows in R data frame

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have imported some raw data into R that looks like this:

Table1:

```
ID    Year    Value
01    1999       25
01    2000       12
01    2002       14
02    1998       16
02    2003        0
02    2004       14
```

The table is sorted by ID and Year, but as you can see, some years are missing. I know from the source of the data that the Value for these missing years should be zero. I have another variable I have called MODEL_YEAR, and set to 2015. I would like to fill in the gaps, up to and including the MODEL_YEAR.

The steps I thought I would take are:

1. Select the earliest year for each ID in table 1.
2. Build a new table (Table2) with consecutive years from each ID's earliest year, up to the MODEL_YEAR.
3. Join Table1 to Table2 to add the Values back in, and replace any NA Values with zero.

I think I can do steps 1 and 3, but haven't been able to work out how to do Step 2, building Table2.

Any help would be appreciated, or suggestions for alternative methods if you think my approach is not optimal.

Thanks

Comment: If I got you right you want to use `2015` as the last year but what's about the first one ?

Comment: The first one varies by ID - that's why in Step 1 I thought I would select the first year for each ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `tidyr::expand()` would be useful. Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
# how to build table2
table2 <- table1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Earliest.Year = min(Year)) %>%
        select(-Value, -Year) %>% distinct() %>%
        expand(Year = Earliest.Year:2015, Earliest.Year) %>%
        select(-Earliest.Year)

# a direct piepe solution
table1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Earliest.Year = min(Year)) %>%
        select(-Value, -Year) %>% distinct() %>%
        expand(Year = Earliest.Year:2015, Earliest.Year) %>%
        select(-Earliest.Year) %>%
        left_join(table1, by = c("ID", "Year")) %>%
        replace(is.na(.), 0)
# output
# A tibble: 35 x 3
# Groups:   ID [?]
      ID  Year Value
   <int> <int> <dbl>
 1     1  1999    25
 2     1  2000    12
 3     1  2001     0
 4     1  2002    14
 5     1  2003     0
 6     1  2004     0
 7     1  2005     0
 8     1  2006     0
 9     1  2007     0
10     1  2008     0
# ... with 25 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks. This works great with the example data I provided. For some reason, when I try to use "expand" on my actual data I get the message "Warning message: In status2$srdd:MODEL_YEAR : numerical expression has 13068083 elements: only the first used".  Not sure why this is happening, am trying to figure it out...

Comment: This warning message states that you have a whole column of 13068083 values `2015` (i.e. `status2$MODEL_YEAR`) but only the first value of this column is used. Since the first value is `2015` everything should be ok but you can avoid this warning message by setting `MODEL_YEAR` as a vector of length 1 (`MODEL_YEAR <- 2015`) instead of a variable in your data frame

Answer (score 2):

Since `tidyr::expand()` is already taken, there is slightly different solution with `tidyr::complete`:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  bind_rows(
    mutate(dat, Year = 2015, Value = 0) %>% unique()
  ) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%                           # allows to start from earliest year
  complete(Year = full_seq(Year, 1), ID) %>% # expand years up 2 2015 for each ID
  mutate(Value = coalesce(Value, 0)) %>%     # fill NAs by zeros
  ungroup()
```

Which outputs:

```
# A tibble: 35 x 3
    Year ID    Value
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
 1  1999 01       25
 2  2000 01       12
 3  2001 01        0
 4  2002 01       14
 5  2003 01        0
 6  2004 01        0
 7  2005 01        0
 8  2006 01        0
 9  2007 01        0
10  2008 01        0
# ... with 25 more rows
```

Data I used:

```
dat <- read.table(
  text = "ID    Year    Value
          01    1999       25
          01    2000       12
          01    2002       14
          02    1998       16
          02    2003        0
          02    2004       14",
  header = T,
  colClasses = c("character", "integer", "integer")
)
```

Comment: Regarding the line "ID = c("01", "02")" - my actual data has thousands of IDs - is there a way to do this without naming them all?

Comment: Simplest would be `ID = unique(dat$ID)` or `ID = unique(.$ID)`

Answer (score 1):

**1) Base R** Use `by` to split `table1` by `ID` and for each component `rbind` it to a data frame having the same `ID`, each desired `Year` and `Value` of 0.  Then aggregate that using `sum` and finally use `rbind` to combine the components back together.

```
do.call("rbind", by(table1, table1$ID, function(x) {
  r <- rbind(x, data.frame(ID = x$ID[1], Year = x$Year[1]:MODEL_YEAR, Value = 0))
  aggregate(Value ~ ID + Year, r, sum)
}))
```

giving:

```
     ID Year Value
1.1   1 1999    25
1.2   1 2000    12
1.3   1 2001     0
1.4   1 2002    14
1.5   1 2003     0
1.6   1 2004     0
1.7   1 2005     0
...etc...
```

**2) dplyr**  This uses the same approach but is translated to use dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)

table1 %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 do(bind_rows(., data.frame(ID = .$ID[1], Year = .$Year[1]:MODEL_YEAR, Value = 0))) %>%
 group_by(Year, add = TRUE) %>%
 summarize(Value = sum(Value)) %>%
 ungroup
```

### Note

`table1` is reproducible form:

```
table1 <-
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Year = c(1999L, 
2000L, 2002L, 1998L, 2003L, 2004L), Value = c(25L, 12L, 14L, 
16L, 0L, 14L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

MODEL_YEAR <- 2015
```